# Table customer_grid_flat delted after reindex magento

Tags: magento2, reindex

I have my project in amazon server. when I run `indexer_reindex` the table `customer_grid_flat` is deleted and I get an error as below

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid
>   attribute name: path

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: i reinstalled magento 2 projetc*